# Alamofire callback never returns

Tags: ios, swift, http, networking

I'm using Alamofire library to make a GET request to stackexchange api, and I want to save the results that I got from the JSON in a array, the problem is that the alamofire task is async and I need the data provided by it to do my work such as table cell insertion etc...I tried to use a semaphore to make my program wait for the call but the call never reaches signal().Why does that happen ? Is it another way to continue my work after the async call terminates? I'm very new to this stuff so I don't know very much , any help is appreciated. Code bellow:

```
var users:[UserInfo] = []
var number:Int = 0
let dispatch:DispatchSemaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)


override func viewDidLoad() {

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    // GET the data from the stackexchange api

    let param: Parameters = [
        "order": "desc",
        "max" : 10,
        "sort" : "reputation",
        "site" : "stackoverflow"
    ]

    Alamofire.request("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users", method: .get, parameters: param).responseJSON { (response) -> (Void) in


        if let json = response.result.value {
            // we got a result

            /* I know this is a bit ugly */
            let json1 = json as! [String:AnyObject]
            let usersInfoFromJSON = json1["items"] as! NSArray       // remember to cast it as NSDictionary


            for userInfo in usersInfoFromJSON {

                self.number = 70 // just for test

                let userDict = userInfo as! NSDictionary
                self.users.append(UserInfo(newName: userDict["display_name"] as! String,
                       newImageURL: userDict["profile_image"] as! String))
            }
        }
        self.dispatch.signal()
    }
    self.dispatch.wait()


    print(self.number) // just for test

    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

Comment: You really don't want to block the main thread with self.dispatch.wait()

Comment: Yea , you are right but what would be the solution ?

Comment: First, just get rid of the DispatchSemaphore. Do whatever you need to do in the closure of the Alamofire.request call. In the example above, put the `print(self.number)` where you currently have the `self.dispatch.signal()` You may want to have a call from there to update the UI, stop a spinner, whatever.

Comment: yea, that would do it but i have other functions like those needed for TableViewDelegate that need the data provided by the alamofire call

Comment: same principle applies, call those functions from the closure. The table view delegate will just have to handle not having data right away. Once you have the data, you can call tableview.reloadData() to display it.

Comment: Ooh , the tableview.reloadData() solved my problem , that was it, thank you so so much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, get rid of the DispatchSemaphore. The way you are using it will block the main thread. Very bad idea.

It might be as easy as calling `tableView.reloadData()` from the closure. I would also recommend putting the data loading into a separate function, in case at some point you want to refresh the data from the source.

```
var users:[UserInfo] = []
var number:Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    loadData()

    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func loadData() {
    // GET the data from the stackexchange api
    let param: Parameters = [
        "order": "desc",
        "max" : 10,
        "sort" : "reputation",
        "site" : "stackoverflow"
    ]

    Alamofire.request("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users", method: .get, parameters: param).responseJSON { (response) -> (Void) in
        if let json = response.result.value {
            // we got a result

            /* I know this is a bit ugly */
            let json1 = json as! [String:AnyObject]
            let usersInfoFromJSON = json1["items"] as! NSArray       // remember to cast it as NSDictionary

            for userInfo in usersInfoFromJSON {
                self.number = 70 // just for test

                let userDict = userInfo as! NSDictionary
                self.users.append(UserInfo(newName: userDict["display_name"] as! String,
                       newImageURL: userDict["profile_image"] as! String))
            }
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
        print(self.number) // just for test
    }
}
```

If you want to get clever, you can even move the reloadData() into a `didSet` closure of `users`. Of course, if you do this, remove the `reloadData()` call from the Alamofire closure.

```
var users:[UserInfo] = [] {
    didSet {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```